# RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image]

Why i am getting error for Laravel relationship. I am trying to print_r the values with this relationship. is there any way to get rid of this error?

**Controller:** this is cart page functions

```
public function cart_page()
{
    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
    $viewData = cartmodel::with('product_tbls')->where('session_id', $session_id)->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($viewData); 
    die;

    // return view('pages.cart', compact('viewData'));
}
```

**Products_model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product_models extends Model
{
    protected $table = "product_tbls";

    public function shop_product_all()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\cartmodel');
    }    
}
```

**Cart model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class cartmodel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "shoppingcart";

    public function shopcart_product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\product_models');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your relationship method is `shopcart_product()`

Comment: function name will be same?

Comment: `cartmodel::with('shopcart_product')`. Make sure you mention correct foreign keys.

Comment: [shopcart_product] => giving empty value, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing `with('shopcart_product')`, I just append `product_id` in model like,

```
public function shopcart_product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\product_models', 'product_id);
}
```

Now getting values from `product_tbls`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a relationship which isn't defined. I think you're passing table name in `with` which should be relationship function as vivek_23 mentioned in comment. So try the below code:

```
public function cart_page()
{
    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
    $viewData = cartmodel::with('shopcart_product')->where('session_id', $session_id)->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($viewData); 
    die;

    // return view('pages.cart', compact('viewData'));
}
```

Comment: but , [shopcart_product] => giving empty value

Comment: Maybe your cart is empty! Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: image value from products_model

Comment: Are you sure your cart model has image value?

Comment: try `dd($session_id)`